# Reset Password function in Flask-Security not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I'm trying to use the default Forgot Password functionality in Flask-Security module with no customizations.  On the Forgot Password view, I enter my email address, click Recover Password and successfully receive the reset password email.  When I click the link in the email, I go to the Reset Password view as expected.  When I try to enter a new password and submit, I get this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/views.py", line 264, in reset_password
    update_password(user, form.password.data)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/recoverable.py", line 78, in update_password
    _datastore.put(user)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/datastore.py", line 31, in put
    self.db.session.add(model)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1371, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1383, in _save_or_update_state
    self._save_or_update_impl(state)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1639, in _save_or_update_impl
    self._update_impl(state)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1633, in _update_impl
    self._attach(state)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1721, in _attach
    state.session_id, self.hash_key))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0xa362a4c>' is already attached to session '33' (this is '34')
```

Can anyone help with this?

I'm using: Flask==0.9, Flask-SQLAlchemy==0.16, Flask-Security==1.5.4